# How to add a view by context in Android

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity, android-context

I have a Main class and a OtherClass. I want to add a view by the OtherClass in the Main class but have a problem.

Main Activity:

```
public class Main(){

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ScrollView MainScrollView = new ScrollView(this);
    this.setContentView(MainScrollView);

    RelativeLayout MainRelLay = new RelativeLayout(this);
    MainScrollView.addView(MainRelLay);

    OtherClass obj = new OtherClass(this);
    MainRelLay.addView(OtherClass());       

}
```

I have the OtherClass:

```
public class OtherClass{

 public OtherClass(Context cnt){

    EditText et = new EditText(cnt);

    ((Activity) cnt).addContentView(et, null);

 }

}
```

Comment: You should use the observable pattern. The child announces the main class via some event. The mainclass decides on how to react(handle) to this event. In Your case you would add a view.

Answer (score 0):

My solution,
MainActivity :

```
public class Main(){

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

ScrollView MainScrollView = new ScrollView(this);
this.setContentView(MainScrollView);

RelativeLayout MainRelLay = new RelativeLayout(this);
MainScrollView.addView(MainRelLay);

OtherClass obj = new OtherClass(this,MainRelLay);       
}
```

Other Class :

```
public class OtherClass{

public OtherClass(Context cnt, RelativeLayout layout){

EditText et = new EditText(cnt);

layout.addView(et);

}

}
```